# Getting a certificate error whenever i run any web app in visual studio 2022

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

The message i am getting is "Adding the certificate to the trusted root certificate store failed with the following error" and then it says "Failed with an error."

And there is no other information!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have created new projects using the standard templates, and still the same problem without changing anything....

Comment: [A fix for this issue has been released!](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Installing-VS2022-breaks-dotnet-tool/1575432) Install the most recent release from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

in command prompt type **where.exe dotnet**
if display like this:

C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\dotnet.exe

C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe

you need move up C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe in Start Menu - Edit the System Environment variables - Environment Variables - Path - Edit

after maybe need create certificate **dotnet dev-certs https --trust**

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much!

Comment: Thank you, worked for me too. Would never have thought of this

Comment: This worked for me after installing VS 2022 Current. Other symptoms I noticed before doing this are that "dotnet --list-sdks" returned an empty list and VS complained about missing SDKs before making this Path change.

Comment: Juste to clarify :
- Add dotnet.exe to Environment Variables using its path in order to use it as CLI.
- Execute : dotnet dev-certs https --trust